# How to disable JSON values autocomplete in webstorm 2020.3

Tags: webstorm

I was forced to update webstorm because it couldn't retrieve the license. Now I have new features, and one of these is JSON values autocomplete. I can't find where to disable it. It disturbs me a lot.

[image]

Comment: Currently there's no way to disable these completion suggestions. Please vote for this issue: https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/WEB-48502

Comment: So Jetbrains just added a "feature" that is annoying as hell and does not allow to disable it. This IMO degrades UX experience.

Comment: Can I disable it in config file? There were some features that one could disable by editing config files.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Starting with WebStorm 2020.3.3 suggestions for the string literals are shown only on pressing Ctrl-Space. See [WEB-49259](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/WEB-49259).